# Can I run multiple chi-square for each conditions?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

HI supposed I have these conditions.

```
    dt = structure(list(sunny = 21:22, shade = 3:2
, tree = c(384L, 807L), hat = c(24L, 43L))
, row.names = c("Control", "Treated" )
, class = "data.frame")

> dt
        sunny shade tree hat
Control    21     3  384  24
Treated    22     2  807  43
```

What I'm interested is if there is a difference **within each group and not across**. So for example I'm interested if there is a difference between control and treated in tree, and hat and so on.

Can I do something like this?

```
     set.seed(123)
     chisq.test( as.table(as.matrix( dt[, 1]  ))  , simulate.p.value = TRUE)
     chisq.test( as.table(as.matrix( dt[, 2]  ))  , simulate.p.value = TRUE)
     chisq.test( as.table(as.matrix( dt[, 3]  ))  , simulate.p.value = TRUE)
     chisq.test( as.table(as.matrix( dt[, 4]  ))  , simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

so that I will end with 4 p.values and just correct with Bonferroni?

Comment: There were 3 shades in the control and 2 shades (whatever it means) among the treated. What do those 3 and 2 mean, and why may this difference relate to the treatment?  Could "shades" migrate to "trees" as a result of the treatment?

Comment: @Alex subjects collect buried items. 
they run around in different areas, sunny, shade,tree, hat. 
in each areas are the total gems that were collected. 
What I don't need to do is compare between sunny,shade or tree but whether there was a difference
within the tree area, that is did the treament group collected more rocks there than the none treated, and so on for each area.

Comment: The situation that you describe is very complex and statistically unusual. Because there are several subjects (and the numbers in the contingency table aren't them). Those subjects collect the items consecutive. This collection is not independent between the subjects (if the item is found by one treated subject, it cannot be collected by another treated subject or by a control subject). If a subject collects an item now he or she can't collect another item at the same time, because he or she is busy. These are all very relevant factors for modeling. Chi-2 won't work in any case.

Comment: @Alex sorry I was not clear;  all items can be collected by any subjects since they are just replaced and moreover subjects can collect as many items as they can between any of the conditions. May be I need to edit the post to describe this better?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I added my suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following then

```r
chisq.test(x=dt[,1], p=c(0.5, 0.5))
```

Comment: thanks; follow up question if I run this 4 times, for 1..4 can I just simply multiply by 4 to get the Bonferroni correction?

Comment: You actually can. It will be pretty conservative.